# Is a TPM which boots a full-disk-encrypted computer to login secure?

Tags: windows, disk-encryption, tpm

Currently the laptops in use are encrypted using Pre-Boot-Authentication, so the entire disk is encrypted. A user has to enter a password before booting the operating system.

A new concept suggests using the laptops TPM to store the key. While the disk itself is still fully encrypted, the boot process continues until the Windows Login Screen **without** the user entering a password.

On these laptops, USB-drives are not blocked before login and BIOS (tries to) prevent(s) booting from another drive (which can probably be bypassed). In my opinion, this makes the Full-Disk-Encryption as secure as the Windows login screen, which is a considerable downgrade.

The question is:

**Is allowing the boot process to continue until the Windows Login Screen without requiring the user to enter a password considered secure?**

**Which attack vectors can be used and are they just academic problems or reasonably possible?**

Assume the laptops are corporate devices, containing potentially sensitive/internal data. I argued that any flaw in the Windows Login Screen effectively kills the Full-Disk-Encryption. Any software like KonBoot may be used to nullify the encryption. A colleague mentioned, that employees leave their devices in sleep mode 80-90% of off-work hours, so it doesn't really matter, even when using the pre-boot-authentication which is currently in place.

Comment: Not the topic, but: `A colleague mentioned, that employees leave their devices in sleep mode 80-90% of off-work hours,` This is the very first thing you need to fix. Eg. by telling them (and following through with it) that certain security procedures needs to be done or they are fired.

Comment: +1 Agreed. I also see this as a crucial problem. Many employees do this out of convenience, as booting the machines takes times (this pre-boot-authentication combined with the absurd Windows startup time is far from optimal).

Comment: @deviantfan : enforce entering password after "unsleep" is pretty straightforward.

Comment: There is no utility or os you could boot from USB that would be able to read the encrypted drive without providing the password.

Comment: @GxTruth Absurd windows startup time?? When was the last time you tried using windows? Windows 10 on an SSD can easily start in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Windows by default requires a password after sleep. Sleep mode is not a security risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my opinion, this makes the Full-Disk-Encryption as secure as the Windows login screen, which is a considerable downgrade.

Yes. And in a sanely configured, domain joined, patched, laptop, this is fairly secure.

As the disk is encrypted, you can not bypass the login my editing configuration files easily. You can not decrypt the disk if the TPM refuses to unseal, which it should refuse if boot options has changed.

It will reduce security over having to enter a pass code on boot. It will also increase convenience and probably reduce number of support calls. It will for sure thwart opportunistic thieves, that find or steal a laptop without any aim, from discovering the content.

You will have to balance this against who and what you protect. An answer applicable to the budget spreadsheet of Moms & Pop Cornerstore LTD may not be applicable to the engineering drawings of Boeing - to take two extreme examples.